# How to Implement class Alkio?

Tags: java

I have following problem to be solved in java: Implement class Alkio. Test with a done main programme AlkioPaa.java with which you see that your class functions.
My answer to this question is following:

```
/**
* @author A.
* @version 28.11.2011
* Tehtävä5. Ohjelma Toteuttaa luokan Alkio  */

public class Alkio {
  private int rivi;
  private int sarake;
  private int arvo;


   public Alkio(int rivi, int sarake, int arvo){
    int Rivi= rivi;
    int Sarake=sarake;
    int Arvo=arvo;
  }

  public void setAlkio(int rivi, int sarake, int arvo){
    System.out.println("("+rivi+","+sarake+","+arvo+")");
  }

  public int getArvo(){
    return arvo;
  }

  public int getRivi(){
    return rivi;
  }

  public int getSarake(){
    return sarake;
  }

  //jotain häikkää seuraavassa( 28.11.2011). Häikkä poistunut(29.11.2011)
  public String toString(){
    String merkkijono= new String();
    return merkkijono;
  }
}
```

Are there any comments?
Then Test is done with main programme AlkioPaa.java which is following:

```
public class AlkioPaa {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Alkio eka = new Alkio(1,2,10);

    System.out.println("Tein alkion, jonka rivi on " + eka.getRivi() 
       + " ja sarake on " + eka.getSarake() + ". Arvo on " + eka.getArvo());


    System.out.println("\n alkio on " + eka.toString());

    String apu = eka.toString();

    System.out.println("alkio " + apu);

    eka.setAlkio(2, 5, 12);

    System.out.println("Muutettu alkio " + eka);
  }
}
```

When I run main-program it prints:

```
Tein alkion, jonka rivi on 0 ja sarake on 0. Arvo on 0
```

alkio on
alkio
(2,5,12)
Muutettu alkio
So it does not print (1,2,10) as should be.

Comment: Please format your code properly next time.

Comment: Please tag homework as such! The code you pasted even has the assignment number left :P

Comment: In addition to what MByD commented on in his answer, I'd also like to point out that it's very unintuitive to have a function `setAlkio` which doesn't set "Alkio", but instead just prints out the parameters it receives.

Comment: @flesk - ha! totally missed that!

Comment: @flesk: So do you mean that method setAlkio is not right, but needs correction. What would these corrections be?

Comment: @alvoutila: You should replace `System.out.println("("+rivi+","+sarake+","+arvo+")");` with `this.rivi = rivi; this.sarake = sarake; this.arvo = arvo;`.

Comment: I get following when I have made these changes. What should the return type of setAlkio be?
.\Alkio.java:15: invalid method declaration; return type required
  public setAlkio(int rivi, int sarake, int arvo){
         ^
AlkioPaa.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setAlkio(int,int,int)
location: class Alkio
    eka.setAlkio(2, 5, 12);
       ^
2 errors

Comment: @All: I have hard time figuring out how this question of mine would get some upvotes so that I might receive my ability to ask questions. So do you have some hints on how to improve my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you expect it to print (1,2,10)?

1. You re-set the values to 2,5, 12 (`eka.setAlkio(2, 5, 12);`). (although, as commented to the question by @flesk, you don't actually set them...)
2. you didn't override the `toString` method as you should have:

   ```
   public String toString(){
       return "("+rivi+","+sarake+","+arvo+")";
   }
   ```
3. In your constructor, you don't set the class members to the given parameters, because you hide them in the method, the constructor should be:

   ```
   public Alkio(int rivi, int sarake, int arvo){
       this.rivi= rivi;
       this.sarake=sarake;
       this.arvo=arvo;
   }
   ```

Comment: Why it is this and not any other e.g. that? And why you put this.rivi=rivi;this.sarake=rivi; this.arvo=rivi; and not int Rivi=rivi; int Sarake=sarake; int Arvo=arvo;?

Comment: @alvoutila: `this` is a reserved keyword and references the current object. That is when you use `this.rivi = rivi` in your constructor you are saying that the object variable `rivi` should take the value of `rivi` passed into the constructor as an argument. Note that they are two different variables. When you write `int Rivi = rivi` you're declaring a third variable that is local to the constructor and breaking java naming conventions in one fell swoop.

Comment: How do you import this Alkio-class into a class( e.g. public class T6 {...)? import Alkio;?

Comment: If it is in the same package, you don't need to import it, otherwise - `import packagename.Alkio;`

Comment: @MByD: I have still problems to be solved. When I make import Alkio; => 
T6.java:5: '.' expected
import Alkio;
            ^
T6.java:5: ';' expected
import Alkio;
             ^
T6.java:6: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.lang.Math;
       ^
3 errors
What to do?

Comment: @MByD: Do I create Alkio - object by Alkio suurin=new Alkio(0,0,0); or Alkio suurin=new Alkio();? If I make Alkio suurin=new Alkio();( and import Alkio is not in code) then it says: 
T6.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Alkio()
location: class Alkio
    Alkio suurin=new Alkio();
                 ^
1 error
...

Comment: @alvoutila: If you want to instantiate Alkio with the three parameters set, you should use the three argument constructor you already have (provided that you fix it like MByD has shown). The reason why you get an error when you use `new Alkio()` is that it tries to create the object with the default constructor, which has to be declared explicitly when you create another constructor.