# Why those methods which are used has just one parameter although methods require values of two elements?

Tags: java

> Class Alkio of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309295/how-to-implement-class-alkio)! question is chosen to do more methods.
>   Implement to the class in addition to the previous ones following
>   methods:
>
> ```
> public boolean suurempiArvo(Alkio verrattava)
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> public int compareTo(Alkio verrattava)
> ```
>
> Method `suurempiArvo` returns true, if the value of the object is
>   greater than value of verrattava. Method `compareTo` compares the
>   values of elements and returns an integer( negative, if the value of
>   the object is less that value of verrattava, zero, is values are the
>   same and otherwise positive)

Questions.

Why those methods which are used has just one parameter although methods require values of two elements? If I refer in the methods to verrattava by writing verrattava, how do I refer to object?

Comment: People are downvoting because: 1. your question is incomplete. it references to another question without a link 2. Normally you should post a piece of almost working.

Comment: @Roman B: I believe _my previous question_ refers to the previous question by his/her teacher, not alvoutila's question.  I'd say the downvoting here is too harsh.

Comment: @AleksG then it even worse.. I believe we should not edit and improve questions of new users. They will get used to it, or?

Comment: @Roman B: You could argue either way.  Doing it once isn't too bad, maybe, the user would get a hint and format properly the next time around.

Comment: I need to hear the possible improvements that I can make to make this question more upvoted. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a method

```
public int compareTo(SomeObject other) {
    // needs implementation
}
```

You are comparing `other` with the current instance. That is to say, the reason why you do not need the second element in the signature is that the second element is already there, it's the object whose method is being invoked. You compare the members of `other` with the members of the present instance, basically `this`, in order to arrive at the proper result.

```
public int compareTo(SomeObject other) {
    // assumes member variable foo
    if (this.foo > other.foo) {
        // you finish implementation 
    } 
}
```

For clarification, if you were to invoke these methods, it would be something like

```
SomeObject first = new SomeObject();
SomeObject second = new SomeObject();
int result = first.compareTo(second);
```

So you pass the `second` object into the `compareTo` method of `first`. `first` then compares *itself* against the `second` (`this` vs. `other`).

Comment: Do I need to use this.foo, because public int compareTo( SomeObject other) is a method not constructor? So don't you think only foo is enough, because you use the method compareTo like following: Alkio eka = new Alkio(1,4,10); ... eka.compareTo(Alkio verrattava)? But don't you think we have to create also verrattava( so: Alkio verrattava = new Alkio(1,5,13)?

Comment: You do not need to use `this.` *explicitly* unless necessary for disambiguation (such as if you had a local variable of the same name). I merely included it for its explicitness in the demonstration as means of showing comparing this instance's foo to the other instances foo. In either case, the `other` (or `verrattava`) would also need to be an active instance (or you would need to be able to handle a null pointer).

Comment: So is it now question about created object(e.g. eka) and created object(?) verrattava as an active instance of class Alkio?

Comment: Not sure entirely what you're getting at, unfortunately. Check the update to my answer to see if it helps.

Comment: I have problem implementing public boolean suurempiArvo(Alkio verrattava), because Alkio-class and object consists of three attributes. How I would get required method that checks if the value of the object is greater than value of verrattava? I've got following so far.
  public boolean suurempiArvo(Alkio verrattava) {
    if( this.rivi> verrattava.rivi) {
      return true;
    }
  }

Comment: Perhaps if you translated what "suurempiArvo" means in english? Keep in mind, this is an english language site and us Americans, particularly, are unfortunately not as multilingual as other people around the world.

Comment: suurempiArvo~greaterValue ~Method suurempiArvo returns true, if the value of the object is greater than value of verrattava

Comment: Thank you. To that, I would say it is up to you to decide what takes priority, if anything. Relational comparisons (greater than, less than) for multi-property items are non-trivial, and I can't tell you what is *the* right way, because that's not always going to be the same. One common technique is to use each member as a tiebreaker. That is to say, look at `member1` (where `member1` is the most important member). If `member1` is equal to the other, look at `member2`. If those are equal, look at `member3`. If any comparison is ever unequal, then return true or false as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Object would appear to refer to the instance of the Alkio class that you're calling the method on, so you'd refer to it using `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to a tutorial on Java classes - and also the `compareTo` method of `Comparable` interface.  The simple answer to your question is that you are dealing with two objects: `verrattava' and the object itself, referrd to with`this`, e.g.`this.value1`.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10) - it's not very well formatted, but does give you the idea - scroll down to an example at the bottom.